# posted variable not passing inside query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here `$place = $_POST['place'];` in *listplace.php* doesnot retreive data from the ajax call at *ajaxcall.php*

But the code runs other than this issue it works properly, only the $place not getting into how much ever i try! Please help..

listplace.php file

```
<?php
//connect to the mysql
$db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die("Could not connect database");
@mysql_select_db('ajaxtest', $db) or die("Could not select database");

$place = $_POST['place'];

$sql = @mysql_query("select product_name from products_list where product_name='$place'");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r['product_name'];
}

if (count($rows)) {
    echo json_encode(['option'=> $rows]);
}else {
    echo json_encode(['option'=> false]);
}
?>
```

ajaxcall.php file

```
<select id="name">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
</select>

<?php if (isset($_GET['place']) && $_GET['place'] != '') { ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {place: '<?= $_GET['place'] ?>'},
            url: 'listplace.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.option.length) {
                    var $el = $("#name"); 
                    $el.empty(); // remove old options
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.option.length; i++) {
                        $el.append($('<option>',
                            {
                                value: json.option[i],
                                text: json.option[i]
                            }));
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('No data found!');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
  <?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: use like this '<?= $_GET["place"] ?>'

Comment: Can we see the rendered javascript after PHP has processed it?

Comment: Also, stop using mysql_ commands, they have been removed from the latest versions of PHP. I thoroughly recommend you use PDO, as it is far more secure and can protect you against SQL injection hacking.

Comment: Fixing the syntax error will still leave you with an unmaintainable project Why are you doing this, it doesnt make any sense. Take a step back and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong sequence of quotes ..  you must use different type of quotes  (eg: duoble) inside a string quoted  with single quotes

```
data: {place: '<?= $_GET["place"] ?>'},
```

otherwise you have a wrong formed  string and error in js

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
data: {place: '<?= $_GET['place'] ?>'},
```

to

```
data: {place: '<?= $_GET["place"] ?>'},
```